# C# Trying to make my own List with a static index counter

Tags: list, ienumerable, icollection, enumerator

I want to make my own `List` which has the ability to work in `foreach loop`. As well as have other important commands a `List` has like IndexOf (which is the only thing I don't like about List, since it's dynamically changing). The one in my List has to keep track of all indexes. As well as `Add`, `Contains`, `Count`, `Remove`, as well as `[]` accessors (no idea how to do this) so for now `Get` should do the trick.

The List should be casted to a base class called Entity which is shared in between two other Classes Npc / Player for it's similarities.

Anyways I have no control over the client I'm coding this server too, but the protocol specifition requires all players to keep track of indexes without doing any drastic dynamic changes regular List does to index.

I been following a tutorial how to make my own `Collections` I got down to 3 errors which I cannot solve.

```
Argument 3: cannot convert from 'EntityList<T>' to 'EntityList<Entity>'
```

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'EntityList<Entity>'
```

```
The best overloaded method match for 'EntityListEnumerator<T>.EntityListEnumerator(object[], System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int>, EntityList<Entity>)' has some invalid arguments
```

Also i'd like to ask am i doing this right? or something looks dodgy.

Thanks for the help I appreciate it.. this part of C# seems extremely advanced and hard to grasp concept.

Source to EntityList

```
public class EntityList<T> : ICollection<T> where T : Entity
{
        private const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 1600, MIN_VALUE = 1;
        public object[] entities;
        public HashSet<int> indicies = new HashSet<int>();
        public int curIndex = MIN_VALUE;
        public int capacity;

    public EntityList(int capacity) {
        entities = new object[capacity];
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public EntityList() 
    : this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY) {}

public bool Add(T entity)
{
    Add(entity, curIndex);
    return true;
}

    public void Add(T entity, int index) {
        if (entities[curIndex] != null) {
            increaseIndex();
            Add(entity, curIndex);
        } else {
            entities[curIndex] = entity;
            entity.setIndex(index);
            indicies.Add(curIndex);
            increaseIndex();
        }
    }

public T Get(int index)
{
    return (T)entities[index];
}

public void Remove(T entity)
{
    entities[entity.getIndex()] = null;
    indicies.Remove(entity.getIndex());
    decreaseIndex();
}

public T Remove(int index)
{
    Object temp = entities[index];
    entities[index] = null;
    indicies.Remove(index);
    decreaseIndex();
    return (T)temp;
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return new EntityListEnumerator<T>(entities, indicies, this);
}

    private void increaseIndex() {
        curIndex++;
        if (curIndex >= capacity) {
            curIndex = MIN_VALUE;
        }
    }

private void decreaseIndex()
{
        curIndex--;
        if (curIndex <= capacity)
            curIndex = MIN_VALUE;
    }

    public int IndexOf(T entity) {
        foreach(int index in indicies) {
            if (entities[index].Equals(entity)) {
                return index;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

public bool Contains(T entity)
{
    return IndexOf(entity) > -1;
}

    public int Count {
    get
    {
        return indicies.Count();
    }
    }
}
```

Source to EntityListEnumerator

```
class EntityListEnumerator<E> : IEnumerator<E> where E : Entity
{
    private int[] indicies;
        private object[] entities;
        private EntityList<Entity> entityList;

protected int curIndex; //current index
protected E _current; //current enumerated object in the collection

public EntityListEnumerator(object[] entities, HashSet<int> indicies, EntityList<Entity> entityList)
{
        this.entities = entities;
        this.indicies = indicies.ToArray();
        this.entityList = entityList;
    curIndex = -1;
    }

public virtual E Current
{
    get
    {
        return _current;
    }
}

public virtual bool MoveNext()
{
    //make sure we are within the bounds of the collection
    if (++curIndex >= entityList.Count)
    {
        //if not return false
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //if we are, then set the current element
        //to the next object in the collection
        _current = entityList[indicies[curIndex]];
    }
    //return true
    return true;
}

    public void Remove() {
    if (curIndex >= 1)
    {
        entityList.Remove(indicies[curIndex - 1]);
        }
    }

// Reset the enumerator
public virtual void Reset()
{
    _current = default(E); //reset current object
    curIndex = -1;
}

// Dispose method
public virtual void Dispose()
{
    entityList = null;
    _current = default(E);
    curIndex = -1;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm sorry for asking, but why?

Comment: why what? why I'm attempting to do this? well it will be more flexible in the long run, I think it's like hiding the engine in your car under the hood since you know it will function properly you won't have to worry about it too much. Well plus its kinda reusing code since without this class I'd have 2 set of index keepers for both Npc/Player. Meh I don't know why but I want to fix this thanks let me know if you know whats wrong I'm a newbie learning how to do things in C#

Comment: If you mean why didn't I just use List? well List's indexes are dynamic.. I want them to be static.. that about sums it up. Say a player in 500th index logs out.. all players after 500 will be shifted and screw up order of indexes.. hell if the first player logs off.. everyone is screwed.. same with npcs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you need, but did you look at the Dictionary object? You can define your own key and have it hold whatever item you need if you use the generic version

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Just read your last comment:
You could decide not to use the List's index for position but either use the Dictionary i mentioned or just use a List, but instead of using the indexer (the number that will 'screw up') checking a property on the items in the list (have your items in the list hold its own 'index' that you control 100%)

Comment: Can't define my own key.. thats the point the keys have to increment like in a normal List yet.. not shift order. key reuse also must be implemented (use the lowest available keys) then again with what i'm trying to do above all logic will be hidden won't look so messy.